# Why shouldn't I use shouldComponentUpdate in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Previously we used `componentWillReceiveProps()` to update a component on props change. Let's say have a component enable or disable an input field depending on some state in App.js

Now this is marked unsafe and

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Explains several alternatives to use instead.

But I wonder why none of these mention the use of `shouldComponentUpdate()` for this case. I could use

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProp){
    this.setState({
        active: nextProp.active
    });
    return true;
}
```

To set the state of the component active which removes the disabled from an input field.

From reading the docs I couldn't understand why they suggest rather complicated memoization helpers or the componentDidUpdate lifecycle (which only provides previousProbs and thus state that's older than the current state).

Is there a reason not to do it like in my example?

Comment: Because putting logic unrelated to whether or not the component should update in sCU is misleading. It's called that for a reason.

Comment: I don't understand. The component should update (it's active state) on receiving prop

Comment: I think your misunderstanding the wording of the methods name. sCU isn’t “tell me what state properties should be updated”, it’s “tell me if the component should re-render given the current incoming state/props”

Comment: @bxyify Not only what Alexander said, but it would also be easy to create an infinite tender loop this way.

Comment: I thought it was a re-render when I change the state of an element?

Comment: @bxyify No, props too--that's one of the primary features of React. sCU is there as a potential performance boost when you have incoming properties that should *not* cause a re-render. This is all in docs and tutorials though.

Answer (score 3):

shouldComponentUpdate is used in the case that a prop change is causing a re-render that you don't want - you may only care about certain props that affect the rendered view. You can manually inspect nextProps for changes to those specific props and decide to render or not.

You should not modify state (or anything else) inside of shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: I don't understand this

Comment: @bxyify That's non-actionable. *What* don't you understand?.